# Problems with Dropbox and Nautilus in 16.04

Tags: unity, gnome, 16.04, nautilus, dropbox

Like some others I've been having problems that seem to be related to Dropbox requiring a restart of Nautilus, and then I try that but it doesn't work and I get the following message.

In the meantime every tab in Chrome closes when I click on it.

Here is the message I get in terminal:

todd@Dukla:~$ sudo nautilus -q
[sudo] password for todd:

(nautilus:6403): Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
Initializing nautilus-dropbox 2.10.0
todd@Dukla:~$

I assume I'm using Nautilus and Unity -- I just upgraded and the interface is still the same as 14.04.

Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

You installed regular dropbox, and it works, yes?

If memory serves me correctly, nautilus-dropbox is broken. Uninstall it using Synaptic, and you should be fine.

Let us know if that solves your problem, or if you have further questions.

edit: as per our discussion in the comments...

Using Synaptic, enter **dropbox** into the search area, and you should see dropbox, and nautilus-dropbox. Right-click on nautilus-dropbox and select **Mark for complete removal**. Left-click on dropbox and select **Mark for installation**.

Then go back to the search box and enter g15daemon, right-click and select **Mark for re-installation**.

Then click the APPLY icon. After it's done, exit Synaptic. Dropbox may ask you to restart Nautilus by clicking the OK button. Confirm that dropbox is working normally, as expected. See if your problem with Chrome/etc is resolved. If not, start a new question thread.

Comment: "Regular" is the one directly from Dropbox? I do have nautilus-dropbox, but then what's this regular one which should also show in the Synaptic list as installed?

In the meantime I've disabled it to open at startup...

Comment: It looks like nautilus-dropbox has been changed to a link to "regular" dropbox now. In terminal, type: dpkg -l *dropbox*, and lets see what version you have. Cheers, Al

Comment: heynnema
todd@Dukla:~$ dpkg -l dropbox
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
un  dropbox        <none>       <none>       (no description available)
todd@Dukla:~$

Comment: Oh, askubuntu deleted some of my dpkg command. Lets try again... dpkg -l <asterisk>dropbox<asterisk>, replacing <asterisk> with shift-8. Do you have a Dropbox icon in your top panel? Cheers, Al

Comment: I can't follow your command line instructions... tried it several different ways,

Comment: todd@Dukla:~$ dpkg -l *dropbox*
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
un  dropbox        <none>       <none>       (no description available)
ii  nautilus-dropb 2.10.0-2     amd64        Dropbox integration for Nautilus
todd@Dukla:~$

Comment: No, it does not appear in the top panel as I removed it from the Startup Applications

Comment: the command is "dpkg -l *dropbox*", without the quotes, and with one asterisk before, and one asterisk after, the word dropbox. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. I figured out about the same time you posted your most recent comment. So, see results above "todd@Dukla:..."

In addition to the problem with Nautilus and Dropbox, I'm having a problem with the input controls (mouse, keyboard....) doing nothing or just some things with certain apps. But then it passes, for the most part, except that e.g. with Chrome if I click on any tab, it closes, whether or not its on top.

What follows is a report of some errors at the end of an update which seemed otherwise okay. 

(Continued in following message)

Comment: g15daemon
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
A package failed to install.  Trying to recover:
Setting up g15daemon (1.9.5.3-8.3ubuntu2) ...
Job for g15daemon.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status g15daemon.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript g15daemon, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package g15daemon (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 g15daemon

Comment: I've edited my answer. Cheers, Al